# Mac apache needs permissions to write to files

Tags: php, macos, apache, terminal

When testing some PHP on localhost (Mac OSX Mavericks) I've noticed an issue with file permissions.

The following code should read file contents to a variable, add some text to the end of it, then write it back to the original file:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('filename_here');
$fileContent = $fileContent.'added_text_here';
file_put_contents('filename_here',$fileContent);
```

The files being read all have the following permissions set by default:

```
user (me) = Read and write
_www = Read only
everyone = Read only
```

So the file gets read and the content amended but not written back to the file. I'm guessing apache is owned by the _www user. How do I make it so that user has read and write permissions for all files? Alternatively, if anyone thinks that's not the issue, please post an alternative route.

Comment: Read this: http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_file_permissions. In general restrict write permissions as much as you can, don't add them to the whole web site and restrict any uploads to prevent executable files (including php) being uploaded.

Comment: @robjingram thanks but that article doesn't explain how to batch change permissions. I already know how to individually change file permissions.

Comment: Clearly I should have chosen a better article. :)  I'm sure you can track a more complete one on unix file permissions. You can use wildcards for filenames (e.g. chmod 777 *.txt) and also use -R for recursive on a directory (chmod -R 777 my_file_dir). I'd suggest not using 777 though, best to change the group (possibly also to _www) and just assign group write (664). Search for 'chown' and 'chgrp'. BTW, if you are uploading new files as part of this process then the upload folder will also need write permission